# An inequality relating to entries of eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A=[a_{ij}]$ be a $3\times 3$ matrix, where $a_{ii}$ is a real number, and $a_{ji}=\overline{a_{ij}}$ is the complex conjugate of $a_{ij}$ for all $1\leq i,j\leq 3$, i.e $A^t=[\overline{a_{ij}}]$. Let $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$ be eigenvalues of $A$ (not necessarily distinct) and $u_i=(a_i,b_i,c_i)$ be an eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to $\lambda_i$, $i=1,2,3$. Is this true that
$\sum_{i=1}^3\frac{|x_i\overline{y_i}|}{||u_i||^2}\leq 1$, where $x_i,y_i\in\{a_i,b_i,c_i\}$ (not necessarily distinct)? Is this true in general for an $n\times n$ matrix by replacing $n$ with $3$?

Comment: I presume that $x_i,y_i\in\{a_i,b_i,c_i\}$ means that the same element is chosen for each $i$ (so $x_1=a_1$, $x_2=a_2$ is forbidden).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inequality holds for any $n$ if all eigenvalues of the Hermitian matrix $A$  are distinct, so that the eigenvectors form a unitary matrix.$^\ast$

It does not hold if some eigenvalues are identical.
In that case the corresponding eigenvectors need not be orthogonal, you could choose them nearly parallel, say $u_1=(1,0,0)$ and $u_2=(\sqrt{1-\epsilon},\sqrt\epsilon,0)$, with $u_3=(0,0,1)$; then take $x_i=a_i$, $y_i=a_i$, and you find that the inequality is violated:
$$\sum_{i=1}^3\frac{|x_i\overline{y_i}|}{||u_i||^2}=2-\epsilon>1.$$

---

$^\ast$ If the eigenvectors $u_i$ are the rows of an $n\times n$ unitary matrix $U$, the inequality in the OP is the statement that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n |U_{ij}\bar{U}_{ik}|\leq 1,$$
for any pair of integers $j,k\in\{1,2,\ldots n\}$. Define $U'_{ij}=U_{ij}\,\exp\bigl(-i\arg[U_{ij}\bar{U}_{ik}]\bigr)$,
then
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n |U_{ij}\bar{U}_{ik}|\right)^2=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n U'_{ij}\bar{U}_{ik}\right)^2\leq\left(\sum_{i=1}^n|U'_{ij}|^2\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^n|U_{ij}|^2\right)=1.$$

Comment: Thank you Carlo for your answer. Since there exists an orthogonal basis for the whole space of an Hermitian matrix, consisting of eigenvectors, Can we deduce that by choosing these eigenvectors the inequality holds? I mean if we put the elements of orthogonal basis for the whole space as eigenvectors $u_1$, $u_2$ and $u_3$, then we can deduce that the inequality holds. Am I right?

Comment: certainly, all you need is an orthogonal basis.

Comment: Dear Carlo, thank you again for your comments.